# Is there any passage in the Qur'an that is incompatible with US law?

Tags: quran, non-muslim-countries

My friend is saying that Islam is not compatible with Western society, but every single example he gives me is not true!

- For example, in US law it is perfectly fine for me to avoid pork.
- In terms of gender equality for inheritance: "The male shall have the equal of the portion of two females" seems to violate gender discrimination laws. But actually, if I have 2 daughters and 1 son, it is perfectly fine for me to write in my will that 50% of my estate goes to my son and 50% to the 2 daughters.

Is there an instruction in the Qur'an that would be illegal to follow in USA?

Comment: How about marrying more than once. Also maybe the definition of incest maybe different

Comment: @AbuNooh Neither of those are obligations in Islam.

Comment: @AbuNooh: As Ansari pointed out, Muslims do not HAVE to marry more than once. The Qur'an is not telling me that I have to break US law. Ansari: I would click "up" on your comment, but I do not have enough points.

Comment: I believe that your friend is confusing Sharia law with Islam and the holy Qur'an.  There are aspects of Sharia which are not compatible with US law.  Sharia being  derived from both Qur'an and Sahih Hadiths can be confusing to those unfamiliar.  It would be impossible for Muslims in the US to follow Sharia laws and also US laws - you can only serve one master.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be about Islam at all, rather the compatibility of Islam (specifically the Quran) with western society (specifically USA Laws).

Comment: "Any questions on the subject of Islam are welcome here, including but not limited to Islamic law and theology, the Islamic texts, or classical Arabic as it pertains to understanding the above."

This question seems welcome here.

"The following, however, are considered off-topic here except where they're shown to be directly relevant to the religion of Islam: (1) Cultural practices and behaviour of Muslim communities (2) Politics of Muslim-majority countries (3) The Arabic language itself"

My question is none of these.

If there's something you'd like me to change, I'd be happy to :)

Comment: Question doesn't ask for obligation. Either way they're both incompatible just like communism is with capitalism. Islam is a unique way of life with different values. To say it's not is to appease and be defeatist in the mind.

Comment: This is clearly way tooo broad, comparing the whole of Qur'an with all the US laws.. No, no, asking specifically to compare 'an' US law with Islam is fine. You can do that by asking another question